# Codeigniter why session expires just after redirection

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This code was working fine in one pc, but after transfer to another, its not working properly. Session just expires. Here is my code.

```
    public function login($type='') {
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        redirect('user-home');
    }
    $form_action = $this->input->post('action');
    if (!empty($form_action) && $form_action === 'login') {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        if($type == 'X')
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('x_id', 'X Id', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        else
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $message = array('type' => 'danger', 'msg' => 'The email address or password you entered is incorrect.');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
            redirect('login');
        } else {
$user_info = $this->user_model->login($auth_data, $type);

// HERE USER info found properly

            if (!empty($user_info)) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('curr-user', $user_info);
                $this->loginLog();
// HERE USER info found also
                redirect('user-home');
            } else {
                $message = array('type' => 'danger', 'msg' => 'The email address or password you entered is incorrect.');
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
    } else {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

After redirection, one type of user is found in constructor of user_home controller from CI session, but another type(x) is lost.

NOTE:
I have used no database for session

Comment: if no codes were changed (working fine before), and after the transfer, its not working anymore, maybe the problem really isn't really about the code

Comment: just a side-note don't use `'curr-user'` with `-` instead use underscore `_` like `'curr_user'` and try `$this->session->all_userdata()` to see all data in session

Comment: If everything is working fine than check php.ini configuration for session.